# Can anybody read my password protected hard drive files using my hard drive as secondary hard drive?

Tags: password, security

So i have a laptop with ubuntu as OS. now can anyone having physical access to my hardrive ,see my data just by simply using it as secondary hard drive in another laptop or machine?

Comment: Just wondering, do apple use same strategy to prevent data of it's product from   being simply accessed as pendrive ? i know there may be tools through which we can even do that but is this an achievable goal to make my physical drive inaccessible to  another device using any O.S without encryption?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they would be able to access the data. If you want to avoid that, you have to encrypt the data. Here is some information how to use the encrypted "Private" folder or to encrypt your home folder: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome

Here you can find how to encrypt any folder or partition: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/ecryptfs.html

Comment: You may want to store the unwrapped passphrase: http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubt. But isn't it a kind of big deal and why   Ubuntu encrypt data on its own as default or some other mechanism to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need encryption if you want to stop the average user.

The past has proven encryption can also be bypassed through backdoors. There was a newsitem back in 2013 that the NSA [paid](http://www.theverge.com/2013/12/20/5231006/nsa-paid-10-million-for-a-back-door-into-rsa-encryption-according-to) for a backdoor in the RSA encryption. But it is unlikely that the NSA or someone who knew how this backdoor works is the person mounting your disk.

You will not have a 100% guarantee in any case.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubt. But isn't it a kind of big deal and why Ubuntu encrypt data on its own as default or some other mechanism to prevent it?

Comment: We have one called Linux Unified Key Setup (LUKS) though it is not from Ubuntu. Encryption is probably out of the scope of a distribution (low level kernel stuff). LUKS is based on this document: http://clemens.endorphin.org/TKS1-draft.pdf